# bootstrap remove class active from nav

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just can't remove class 'active' from navbar. I tried this :

`$(document).ready(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $('.nav li').removeClass('active');//or $('.active').removeClass('active');
});`

Also tried this:

`setInterval(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');//remove class active
},1000);`

**EDIT:**

This actually works but doesn't work for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('.nav li').removeClass('active');});}
```

I have to mention that I have another navigation in dropdown which probably trigger 'active' class from Twitter Bootstrap Nav Tabs. So I think I can apply this function only on class given to main navigation?
So I tried this:

```
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('.no-active li').removeClass('active');});} </script>
```

HTML:

`<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav no-active">`

But my main navigation still gets class 'active' whenever moving across:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove it in the html? You would add this in your CMS application in the menu functions.

Comment: No html here. 'active' class comes from bootstrap inner functionallity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you're using the Bootstrap nav tabs then this works for me to remove active from the currently active list element

```
$(".nav-tabs > li.active").removeClass("active")
```

I don't think just selecting .nav works because it will select all the elements with 'nav' class (including your main navigation). I'm still not sure I 100% understand your problem, I hope this helps though.

---

I just tried this on the Bootstrap website (do you have a Bootstrap navbar?) using Chrome dev tools and

```
$('.nav li').removeClass("active")
```

works fine for me. Could you give a sample of your HTML?

Comment: I get an error in console: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: @user48915 -- and jQuery is loaded? This is the error I get when it's not

Comment: JQuery must be loaded for sure. I have a couple of functions right before this script.

Comment: `<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav no-active">` this is my main nav. Inside dropdown I have tab nav `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`. When moving across tabs, my main nav li elements are getting active class becouse of the opened tabs.

Comment: So I've tried also this: `$(".navbar-nav > li.active").removeClass("active")` which still does not work.